# Using a single sed call to split and grep

Tags: sed

This is mostly by curiosity, I am trying to have the same behavior as:

```
echo -e "test1:test2:test3"| sed 's/:/\n/g' | grep 1
```

in a single `sed` command.

I already tried

```
echo -e "test1:test2:test3"| sed -e "s/:/\n/g" -n "/1/p"
```

But I get the following error:

```
sed: can't read /1/p: No such file or directory
```

Any idea on how to fix this and combine different types of commands into a single `sed` call?

Of course this is overly simplified compared to the real usecase, and I know I can get around by using multiple calls, again this is just out of curiosity.

EDIT: I am mostly interested in the `sed` tool, I already know how to do it using other tools, or even combinations of those.
EDIT2: Here is a more realistic script, closer to what I am trying to achieve:

```sh
arch=linux64
base=https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com
split="<Contents>"
curl $base \
    | sed -e 's/<Contents>/<Contents>\n/g' \
    | grep $arch \
    | sed -e 's/^<Key>\(.*\)\/chromedriver.*/\1/' \
    | sort -V > out
```

What I would like to simplify is the curl line, turning it into something like:

```sh
curl $base \
 | sed 's/<Contents>/<Contents>\n/g' -n '/1/p' -e 's/^<Key>\(.*\)\/chromedriver.*/\1/' \
 | sort -V > out
```

Comment: Hopefully you've realized now by comparing the sed to the non-sed answers that this is simply not a job for sed.

Comment: I have, but again it is mostly out of curiosity, I really enjoy finding new and weird ways to do things I already know how to... like say, make a 3D engine in bash? I just enjoy learning new and weird stuff, can't help it.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives, `awk` and `sed` based:

```
sed -E "s/(.*:)?([^:]*1[^:]*).*/\2/" <<< "test1:test2:test3"
awk -v RS=":" '/1/' <<< "test1:test2:test3"
# or also 
awk 'BEGIN{RS=":"} /1/' <<< "test1:test2:test3"
```

Or, using your logic, you would need to pipe a second `sed` command:

```
sed "s/:/\n/g" <<< "test1:test2:test3" | sed -n "/1/p"
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/ozwmWr). The `awk` solution looks cleanest.

**Details**

In `sed` solution, `(.*:)?([^:]*1[^:]*).*` pattern matches an optional sequence of any 0+  chars and a `:`, then captures into Group 2 any 0 or more chars other than `:`, `1`, again 0 or more chars other than `:`, and then just matches the rest of the line. The replacement just keeps Group 2 contents.

In `awk` solution, the record separator is set to `:` and then `/1/` regex is used to only return the record having `1` in it.

Comment: I quite like the awk version, but about the sed one I have a couple concerns. 1) The regexs I have shown for splitting and matching are in an overly simplified version, I am quite worried of it "blowing up" in size if I add more complexity to it.
2) The question is more about stacking sed commands than this specific example.

Isn't there a simple way to tell sed to "do `this` then `that` (namely `this == 's/reg/\n/g'` and `that == -n /reg/p`)?

Comment: @Soulthym You do not really have to use `sed` for the current scenario. If you do want it, pipe the second `sed` command: `sed "s/:/\n/g" <<< "test1:test2:test3" | sed -n "/1/p"`

Comment: I get that, I was mainly wondering if there was a way around having to spawn multiple sed instances, without making an overly complicated regex, especially using the sed command

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/:/\n/;/^[^\n]*1/P;D' file
```

Replace each `:` and if the first line in the pattern space contains `1` print it.
Repeat.

An alternative:

```
sed -Ez 's/:/\n/g;s/^[^1]*$//mg;s/\n+/\n/;s/^\n//' file
```

This slurps the whole file into memory and replaces all colons by newlines. All lines that do not contain 1 are removed and surplus newlines deleted.

Comment: This does indeed look very very simple, I like it! I'll try scaling it up to multiple split+match

Comment: On reflection I had forgotten that GNU sed had a way to match at the start of the pattern space when using multiline mode. This would be the equivalent: `sed 's/:/\n/;/\\`.*1/MP;D' file`

Comment: ok so I have tried both, but they end up taking so long, it's been something like 20 minutes since I started the first one and it is not even finished. Is it supposed to take that long?

Comment: I edited the question to show more of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Soulthym one way to speed up the solution would be to globally replace the `:`'s once and once only per line: `sed '/\n/!s/:/\n/g;/\\`.*1/P;D' file`. However if it speed you need perhaps the grep solution would be better.

Answer (score 1):

`echo -e "test1:test2:test3"  | sed -En 's/:/\n/g;/^[^\n]*2[^\n]*(\n|$)/P;//!D'`

- `sed -n` doesn't print unless told to
- `sed -E` allows using parens to match `(\n|$)` which is newline or the end of the pattern space
- `P` prints the pattern buffer up to the first newline.
- `D` trims the pattern buffer up to the first newline
- `[^\n]` is a character class that matches anything except a newline
- `//` is sed shorthand for repeating a match
- `//!` is then matching everything that didn't match previously

So, after you split into newlines, you want to make sure the `2` character is between the start of the pattern buffer `^` and the first newline.

And, if there is not the character you are looking for, you want to `D` delete up to the first newline.

At that point, it works for one line of input, with one string containing the character you're looking for.

To expand to several matches within a line, you have to `ta`, conditionally branch back to label `:a`:

```
$ printf "test1:test2:test3\nbob3:bob2:fred2\n"  | \
    sed -En ':a s/:/\n/g;/^[^\n]*2[^\n]*(\n|$)/P;D;ta'
test2
bob2
fred2
```

Comment: Damn that's more complicated than I thought it'd be, but I like the fact that it would scale up easily!

Comment: @Soulthym - honestly `grep -o` is what you want.

Comment: @Soulthym think about what you're saying - it's more complicated ... and you're considering scaling it up!

Comment: @EdMorton what I mean by scaling it up, is that I can basically just insert another regex to match and that looks like it will work in exactly the same way. Other solutions using `sed` I have seen don't seem to be that simple to scale up (especially those using a single `sed` expression). Here if I want to chain multiple matches/ splits it looks like I can do it with nothing more than adding a new set of these: `s//\n/g;//P;//!D`

Comment: @Soulthym I don't know it it's that simple.  The original line is quite destroyed after one pass through here.... though you could `h` to save it in the hold space, and then `g` to get it back in the pattern space. But sed's convoluted.   I personally jump past awk all the way to perl when it gets too crazy.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the really ugly sed is: `grep -o '\w*2\w*'`

```
$ printf "test1:test2:test3\nbob3:bob2:fred2\n"  | grep -o '\w*2\w*'
test2
bob2
fred2
```

- `grep -o`: only matching

Or: `grep -o '[^:]*2[^:]*'`

Comment: What does `\w` match with specifically? This solution seems to be the simplest although I don't know if it would scale to multiple matchs and operations (splitting in my case) in a much more complicated document. Again my example is overly simplified, in reality I am trying to parse some xml file, splitting on sections, selecting an architecture, splitting on subsections, selecting a specific version etc... Would that be possible with `grep -o`? Also I was mainly curious about how to use sed for this case, but thanks for that suggestion

Comment: \w is a "word character" which is basically letter, number, underscore.  The important thing is that your separator `:` isn't in that class.  The latter regex more explicitly uses the separator.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply NOT a job for sed. With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ echo "test1:test2:test3:test4:test5:test6"| awk -v RS='[:\n]' '/1/'
test1

$ echo "test1:test2:test3:test4:test5:test6"| awk -v RS='[:\n]' 'NR%2'
test1
test3
test5

$ echo "test1:test2:test3:test4:test5:test6"| awk -v RS='[:\n]' '!(NR%2)'
test2
test4
test6

$ echo "foo1:bar1:foo2:bar2:foo3:bar3" | awk -v RS='[:\n]' '/foo/ || /2/'
foo1
foo2
bar2
foo3
```

With any awk you'd just have to strip the `\n` from the final record before operating on it:

```
$ echo "test1:test2:test3:test4:test5:test6"| awk -v RS=':' '{sub(/\n$/,"")} /1/'
test1
```

Comment: Honestly this is pretty neat, I'll think about using it for future projects as it seems way easier to maintain than its `sed` counterpart. Can the last `sub` be combined to multiple regex matching? How about splitting then matching, then splitting again, then matching again? Is that possible? Also can I use whole words as separators? If I can do all these I'll consider using awk more often

Comment: Of course, all of that is clear and trivial to implement. Feel free to ask a new question with sample input and expected output if you have one.